# The return value of function returning long long unsigned int is incorrect

Tags: c

When I call function `wordToInt(c)` from main, the return value is different from what it's printing inside the function.

```
main()
{
    long long  unsigned item;
    char c[6] = "ABCDE";
    item = wordToInt(c);
    printf("Main  The item is :%llu\n",item);
}

long long unsigned wordToInt(char *c)
{
    long long unsigned int k,item=0;
    int i,len;
    int j,p=0;
    len = (int) strlen(c);

    for(i = len-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        if(c[i] == 'c')
            j = 42;
        else if(c[i] == '*')
            j = 99;
        else
            j = (int) c[i];
        j = j%100;
        k = pow(100,p);
        p++;
        item = item + (j*k);
    }

    printf("Function item is :%llu\n",item);
    return item;
}
```

The output of the program is:

```
Function item is :6566676869
Main  The item is :18446744071686293893
```

Can anyone tell me why there is inconsistency in the output?

Comment: *error: initializer-string for char array is too long* - Aren't compilers useful?

Comment: char c[5] = "ABCDE"; Don't you think you should give size as 6. One extra for null character.

Comment: @VikramSingh Even for 6 the same error occurs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First -- pay attention to your compiler's warnings, they matter!

Answer -- since you didn't prototype `wordToInt()` before using it, the compiler warned you that it had not been prototyped and it assumed the function returned an int (which is smaller than a long long)... so you got an int value returned, rather than a long long. The value printed within the function is correct because the function knew the proper type.

Answer (score 2):

Add a declaration of `wordToInt()` before `main()`, or put the body of `wordToInt()` before `main()`.  Either way, the compiler gets to know the prototype of `wordToInt()`, and only so can the arguments be passed and return value be returned correctly.

Comment: Actually i have the wordToInt() function in a different file and compiling along with this file

Comment: @gopi  Then add a declaration of `wordToInt()` before `main()`: `long long unsigned wordToInt(char *c);`

Comment: Basically the problem was with not giving the prototype of the function. So I added the prototype  of the function in the main file and it works fine!

Answer (score 0):

char array when given a string of characters always adds a `NULL` character to the end of the string automatically so make the size to 6

```
char c[6] = "ABCDE";
```

And the output is consistent when i ran the same code with and without changes.

For char size 6

```
Function item is :6566676869
Main  The item is :6566676869
```

For char size 5

```
Function item is :656667686803780408
Main  The item is :656667686803780408
```

EDIT: I added a prototype before function call.

Answer (score 0):

I copied and ran your program and its working. I found the same result in both segments. I don't know why you're getting erroneous answer in the main function. Anyway, here's how i did it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>

long long unsigned wordToInt(char *c)
{

  long long unsigned int k,item=0;
  int i,len;
  int j,p=0;
  len = (int) strlen(c);

  for(i = len-1;i>=0;i--)
  {
          if(c[i] == 'c')
                  j = 42;
          else if(c[i] == '*')
                  j = 99;
          else
                  j = (int) c[i];
          j = j%100;
          k = pow(100,p);
          p++;
          item = item + (j*k);
  }
  printf("Function item is :%llu\n",item);
  return item;
}

int main()
{
    long long unsigned item;
    char c[5] = "ABCDE";
    item = wordToInt(c);
    printf("Main The item is :%llu\n",item);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Then i compiled it with MinGW: gcc -c yourFileName.c
And then for executable: gcc -o executable yourFileName.o

Comment: The problem was using multiple files and i didnt give the prototype of the function in main.